# How to re-create the following table?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've gotten my hands on a word document where there is a table that I've **never** seen before!

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=16183695867954235949) is a link for download of a word document where the table is present.

I've taken a screenshot to explain it:

[image: screenshot]

It looks like all three rows are separate, **but** the red and black is actually connected, when I resize the red X row, the red X row text and border stays the same, but the black X row expands. 

*Note:* *Borders added for better visibility*

The table I'm trying to create has a header row and a *info* row, exactly as this screenshot:

[image: this]

But the problem is, the *info* row thinks that the bottom border of the header is it's top border. That creates a problem when I run my program (*I'm using spire.doc to search and replace in word document*) and the output is this:

[image: this]

So, in short: How do I make the middle border belong to the headers row format and **not** the *infos* format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have applied a border on the paragraph of the text in each cell of row one. The have also set the height of row to a minimum size and specified that the text entered in row one stay at the top of each cell.

Select row 1, cell 1 and then from the Table Layout tab, select Properties and you can adjust these settings.